# dismissViewControllerAnimated is called but ViewController is not dismissed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, ios5

I am having a problems with the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method not closing down the view.

What is happening in the app here is:

- Cell in `ItemViewController` is selected.
- View is **push**ed to `ItemDetailViewController`and details are sent through a delegate
- User selects 'done' and the event is sent via a delegate to be closed in `ItemViewController`

All of this works except for the View is not dismissed, there are no errors. Can anyone see what is wrong?

```
- (void)itemDetailViewControllerDidFinish:(ItemDetailViewController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"Controller: %@", controller);
    // Returns - Controller: <ItemDetailViewController: 0x6b68b60>

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what if you send `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` instead ?

Comment: How does `self` is pushed in the screen?

Comment: @Vince: I did try but it doesn't seem to work if the segue is a 'push'.

Comment: Nekto: If I understand you correctly, self === controller

Comment: @AdTaylor - `self` can't be the VC pushed. Isn't it the VC that presented the second to the user ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

What if you call `[controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` instead?

For that matter, what if you call `[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` instead of calling it on self?

Comment: The exact syntax that worked for me: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Push with pop and present with dismiss

Comment: Looks like self:dismissviewcontroller doesn't work if your page is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: popViewController Worked like a charm

Answer (score 10):

The answer is in this page:
[dismissviewcontrolleranimated-vs-popviewcontrolleranimated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080091/dismissviewcontrolleranimated-vs-popviewcontrolleranimated)

dismissViewController is used when you do not have a navigationcontroller.
Most probably you are using a navigation controller, then use 
  self.navigationController popViewController instead.

Also take note of lemax his remark: use NULL, not nill for the completionhandler

Comment: Use NULL for non-object pointers. So you shouldn't use NULL here.

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem in iOS5 where the standard completion callback was not allowing the view to completely dismiss (only the current pushed view of that modal)

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^ {
     //
 }];
```

**Solution for iOS5** is to not have a callback:

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

Had a problem where calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` dismissed the keyboard in a UIViewController, but not the view itself.

Solved it by using two calls:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

an instant one for the keyboard, then an animated one for the controller

Answer (score 0):

Your Situation is -
ItemViewController -> ItemDetailViewController 
                      (pushed on navigationController)
Self.dismissViewController(..) dismiss a view controller that is presented over self(in ur case it is ItemViewController). Here, u did not presented any VC over self, instead u pushed a new VC over navigation stack. So, Correct way to dismiss ItemDetailViewController would be

self.navigationController.popViewController(true). please read the description of dismissViewController(....) to get more clarity.