# dismissViewControllerAnimated VS popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to know what is the different of them. 
when I can call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and when I should call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

according document of apple:
dismissViewControllerAnimated means
"Dismisses the view controller that was presented by the receiver."
But I always fail to dismiss view controller by this method.

Comment: As for dismiss see [this](https://youtu.be/oTsg-uJfxD4?t=556) video from Stanford. dismissViewController should always be sent to *presenting* viewController. If you send it the *presented* viewController and the presentedViewcontroller had not presented **a**nother viewController *then* it would dismiss it properly otherwise it would not do it right

Answer (score 39, accepted):

your selected application is navigation based application means

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

your selected application is other than the navigation based application means

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: so does it means: I should not use dismissViewControllerAnimated in a navigation based application ? I think it is the reason why I always fail to dismissViewControllerAnimated, thank you !

Answer (score 41):

**-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:**

Used to dismiss an `UIViewController`, which was presented by the method:

`-presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

**-popViewControllerAnimated:**

Method of `UINavigationController` is used to pop a controller shown by

`-pushViewController:animated` method of `UINavigationController`.

In the first case the view controller's view shows as a modal controller (usually from bottom to top), and the second case you are pushing a view controller in the navigation stack of `UINavigationController`.