# Navigate from a view controller to previous view uicollection view controller?

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, ibaction

Actually the scenerio is very simple: on click back button, view controller navigates to previous view controller that have `UICollectionView` in it. I have tried everything but it is not navigating?

I have used stack unwinding using storyboards:

1. `[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];`
2. `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
3. `NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];`

   [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
4. I have also tried all these in `-(IBAction)` and also used satck unwinding ; but its not working.

Comment: Can you share some code/info? What you ask for is pretty much standard behavior when using `UINavigationController`s (push/pop)...

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988992/dismissviewcontrolleranimated-is-called-but-viewcontroller-is-not-dismissed